# How to flatten an array to a matrix in Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am looking for an elegant way to flatten an array of arbitrary shape to a matrix based on a single parameter that specifies the dimension to retain. For illustration, I would like

```
def my_func(input, dim):
    # code to compute output
    return output
```

Given for example an `input` array of shape `2x3x4`, `output` should be for `dim=0` an array of shape `12x2`; for `dim=1` an array of shape `8x3`; for `dim=2` an array of shape `6x8`. If I want to flatten the last dimension only, then this is easily accomplished by

`input.reshape(-1, input.shape[-1])`

But I would like to add the functionality of adding `dim` (elegantly, without going through all possible cases + checking with if conditions, etc.). It might be possible by first swapping dimensions, so that the dimension of interest is trailing and then applying the operation above.

Any help?

Comment: With the corresponding transposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can permute axes and reshape -

```
# a is input array; axis is input axis/dim
np.moveaxis(a,axis,-1).reshape(-1,a.shape[axis])
```

Functionally, it's basically pushing the specified axis *to the back* and then reshaping keeping that axis length to form the second axis and merging rest of the axes to form the first axis.

Sample runs -

```
In [32]: a = np.random.rand(2,3,4)

In [33]: axis = 0

In [34]: np.moveaxis(a,axis,-1).reshape(-1,a.shape[axis]).shape
Out[34]: (12, 2)

In [35]: axis = 1

In [36]: np.moveaxis(a,axis,-1).reshape(-1,a.shape[axis]).shape
Out[36]: (8, 3)

In [37]: axis = 2

In [38]: np.moveaxis(a,axis,-1).reshape(-1,a.shape[axis]).shape
Out[38]: (6, 4)
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.